# how to show all console.log from node.js in heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, nodemailer

I have deployed a node.js application to node.js but not able to see the complete console.log statements from my app. I am using:

```
heroku logs
```

Some of the logging is shown but looks like it is not the complete logs. Is  there a node.js package to send emails from the deployed app? Email works fine from my localmachine btw.

Email code:

```
console.log('try to send email hold on');
    var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "Gmail",
        auth: {
            user: "myemail@gmail.com",
            pass: "mypw"
        }
    });

    smtpTransport.sendMail({
        from: "Dikkebil", // sender address
        to: "myemail@gmail.com", // comma separated list of receivers
        subject: "Error body", // Subject line
        text: 'Error body: ' +error.body+ '\n'+ 'error type:' + error.type +'\n' +'error statuscode:' +error.statusCode +'\n'  + 'error args:' + error.arguments[0]
    }, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what logs are you looking for?

Comment: the console.log logs from my node.js service which is deployed to heroku. I can see them partially. Why does nodemailer 1.3.4 not work on the heroku box?

Comment: nodemailer should work fine on Heroku can you give us your code to look at? I can't understand if you have problems looking at logs or sending email

Comment: @Michelem I have added the emailcode see above.

Comment: Ok what's the problem with that?

Answer (score 50):

From the heroku doc:

> The logs command retrieves 100 log lines by default. You can specify
>   the number of log lines to retrieve (up to a maximum of 1,500 lines)
>   by using the --num (or -n) option.

```
$ heroku logs -n 200
```

So probably you need to request more lines with `-n`option.

As per comment received, you can also stream the current log with:

```
$ heroku logs --tail
```

Please [look at the doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)

Comment: You can also use `heroku logs --tail` to just stream all logs in.

Answer (score 21):

I always use `heroku logs -t --app your-app-name` It keeps the **heroku** console open .

Answer (score 4):

I use:

```
heroku logs -n 1000 --tail
```

that 1000 is the number of lines you want to see and can be up to 1500.

Answer (score 3):

The problems seems to be that the Heroku holds maximum 1500 lines of logs. To persists and have an ability to see more history you have to add some syslog drain to catch the logs or use some addon for that.

There are also "free" addons for storing logs like Logentries and Papertrail https://addons.heroku.com/#logging.