# console.log is not displayed in heroku logs

Tags: heroku

I have the program heroku_test.ts
    `console.log('test')`
I can run it with the following command:
    `heroku run ts-node heroku_test.ts`
In the same console window I see it output 'test'
But when I look at heroku logs, there is no 'test' there, it just says "Starting process with command ts-node heroku_test.ts"

Why heroku logs do not contain console.log output?

EDIT: the question is different from [how to show all console.log from node.js in heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963399/how-to-show-all-console-log-from-node-js-in-heroku) because I can see all the logs except any console.log output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show all console.log from node.js in heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963399/how-to-show-all-console-log-from-node-js-in-heroku)

Answer (score 2):

First install winston :

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston

as follows :

npm install winston --save

Then change your heroku_test.js to the following :

```
const winston = require('winston')

winston.log('info', '-------Hello log files!------------', {  
  someKey: 'some-value'
})
```

Then run

heroku run node heroku_test.js

Then check the logs :

heroku logs --tail

and you should see the above in the heroku logs

Answer (score 1):

you can try some opensource libs, e.g., 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-logger